Как сделать имитацию ответа бота слешом на сообщение?
Мне нужно чтобы бот отправлял картинку на запрос пользователя. Я хочу чтобы он это делал не просто отправив картинку, а именно на то сообщение, которое пользователь напишет ему.
Я знаю, что есть метод bot.reply_to(message, text) но он работает только для отправки текста, а мне нужно чтобы так же бот отвечал, только картинкой. Например:
elif message.text == "1":
    bot.send_photo(TARGET_CHAT_ID, open('1.jpg', 'rb'), message_thread_id=MESSAGE_THREAD_ID)


В sendPhoto есть reply_parameters https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#replyparameters Думаю, нежно использовать его

message_id ????

Да. А что, из описания в документации что-то не понятно?

Я новичок в питон мне не понятно куда в код вставить этот параметр

Просто в конец нужно было добавить параметр:
reply_to_message_id=message.message_id       

Так выглядит полный код:
elif message.text == "1":
    bot.send_photo(TARGET_CHAT_ID, open('1.jpg', 'rb'),
                   message_thread_id=MESSAGE_THREAD_ID, 
                   reply_to_message_id=message.message_id) 


пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]
